# Validate each form element with different rules?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I would like to validate each form element with different rules.

E.g.

- in the "title" element are a-z, A-Z,
  and spaces allowed
- in the "owner" element are a-z and ,
  allowed

Can that be done with JQuery, when I would like to do that in my ajax file?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("form#create_form").submit(function() {

    var title      = $('#title').attr('value');
    var owner      = $('#owner').attr('value');

    // check values
    var is_okay = 0;

    if (title == '') {
        alert('Title is required');
    } else if (owner == '') {
        alert('Owner is required');
    } else {
        is_okay = 1;
    }

        ...
```

Comment: you could create a regular expression pattern and check against that. For instance, `if( /[A-Za-z]|\s/.test( title ) ) { }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't reinvent the wheel and instead use either:

http://validity.thatscaptaintoyou.com/Demos/index.htm

or

http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/